# JSON decoder : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I get the following error on a JSON receive pipeline when calling a REST Get API :

> There was a failure executing the response(receive) pipeline: 
>   "mycustomPiepeline,mycustomPieplelineAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=70f46ad2a5c6e8c0" 
>   Source: "JSON decoder" Send Port: "My webHttp send port" URI: "URL" 
>   Reason: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

and also from an Insomnia call the response is : null

I found [this solution](https://www.connected-pawns.com/2016/01/04/rest-json-christmas-puzzle-work-around/) from Mark's blog by using BRE pipeline framework, but I'm not using BRE.

I think to create a custom component pipeline to replace the null response with an empty body, is there any better suggestions?

I'm using BTS 2016 CU4

Comment: The correct way would be, to make the webservice return a fitting answer. You don't return null but some json string with a message "no data" or something similar.

Comment: it's a partner service, can't ask for this change because it's used by other clients

Comment: In this case you can still write a Helper class which is way more powerful in consuming webservices and error handling. I can not help you, regarding the null exception behaviour in the receive pipeline.

Comment: There is a possible fix from Microsoft, see my updated answer below

Comment: My BTS 2016 is updated by CU4 and the new property is set to "true". I think this fix is to add body to empty messages but not null response

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible fix from Microsoft [FIX: WCF-WebHTTP Two-Way Send Response responds with an empty message and causes the JSON decoder to fail in BizTalk Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020011/fix-wcf-webhttp-two-way-send-response-responds-with-an-empty-message-a) but that was in CU2 for 2016, so it looks like they didn't solve the issue 100% unless you didn't populate the AddMessageBodyForEmptyMessage property.

Mark's solution is more to do with some elements in a JSON payload created by the JSON Encoder having a null value, which itself is a work around for a bug in the JSON Encoder that is changing an empty string into a null.

If you don't want to use the BRE Pipeline Component (which hopefully will be available for BizTalk 2016 very soon as I know it is being worked on), then you can roll your own e.g. below, where InsertInEmpty is a parameter on the Pipeline Component that you can set what message to return if you get a empty body.

```
    #region IComponent members
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements IComponent.Execute method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pc">Pipeline context</param>
    /// <param name="inmsg">Input message</param>
    /// <returns>Original input message</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// IComponent.Execute method is used to initiate
    /// the processing of the message in this pipeline component.
    /// </remarks>
    public Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage Execute(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPipelineContext pc, Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage inmsg)
    {
        string dataOut = "";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inmsg.BodyPart.Data);

        if (InsertInEmpty != "" & inmsg.BodyPart.Data.Length == 0)
        {
                dataOut = InsertInEmpty;               
        }
        else 
        {   
            dataOut = dataOut + sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataOut));
        inmsg.BodyPart.Data = ms;
        inmsg.BodyPart.Data.Position = 0;

        return inmsg;
    }
    #endregion
```